# Diagram of array of 8 8-bit characters

Tags: c++, memory, integer, double, memory-address

The following is a diagram of the memory used by an array of 8 8-bit (1-byte) characters. Do a similar diagram for an array of 8 32-bit integers and 8 64-bit doubles.

```
    Byte (Character)    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
    Index               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
    Address             n   n+1 n+2 n+3 n+4 n+5 n+6 n+7
```

Do you guys have any clue what this means?

Would the Byte of a 32-bit integer be 0001?
What about its address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an exercise designed to get you to think about the difference between array indices and actual memory addresses. The integer at index 1, that is `myarray[1]`, would be found at address `n+4` because a 32-bit integer is 4 bytes wide.

So maybe the 32-bit case would look like this?

```
32-Bit Integer      1     2     3    4    5    6    7    8
Index               0     1     2    3    4    5    6    7
Address             n   n+4   n+8 n+12 n+16 n+20 n+24 n+28
```

Answer (score 1):

I can take a shot at this.  I believe that it is only demonstrating two things:  index is how you would address the data as an array while address is an arbitrary address in memory.

For the 32 bit case (assuming little endian), you would have

```
Word      1                |  2  
Index     0                |  1  
Address   n+0 n+1 n+2 n+3  |  n+4 n+5 n+6 n+7
```

The first 4 address bytes are the little endian 32 bit first word.  The second 4 address bytes are the next 32 bit word.   Just continue.